# how to keep running the code when the program is close in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background-process

how to keep running the code when the program in closed

I want the timer that count in every secound and show it in text but i want to when the app closed still counting

is it possible with the flutter_background_service ?
flutter_background_service 2.4.6

or there is another package to do it?

a simple example would be helpfull